# Making a relative path HTML Shortcut

Tags: html, path, documentation, doxygen, doxywizard

I have pretty much no experience with HTML, but I am using Doxygen to create code documentation. I have all the Doxygen generated HTML files in a sub-directory within my C project.

This documentation is for a library I have built and I would like the user to be able to view the HTML documentation without having to search through the Doxygen sub-directory for `index.html`. I tried to make a Windows shortcut to `index.html`, but that only works on my working computer. Whenever I try on another computer, Windows requests the username and password of my working computer. Then I tried copying the `index.html` file to the top-level of my library; however, in doing so, it seems like many links were broken and the file did not open properly.

Please note that I am not looking to host this documentation on a server, the documentation will be distributed with the source code, since this library is (currently) for internal, educational university use and I am not sure if I am allowed to make it open-source.

In other words, this is the type of file structure I'm looking for:

```
Project Folder
    -Doxygen Documentation Folder
        -index.html
    -Source Code Folder
    -Shortcut to index.html
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a thread **[here](http://doxygen.10944.n7.nabble.com/Separate-and-rename-index-html-td5886.html)** that should help.

Essentially the suggestion is to have a top-level `index.html` that links or redirects the reader to the one in the doxygen folder.  I note you're new to HTML but it's quite simple.

There's an example of a minimal `index.html` you could use towards the bottom of that thread which I'll replicate here in case that thread ever disappears.  It was contributed by Clemens Feige.

```
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; URL=doxygen/index.html"> 
</head> 

<body> 
  <p>You will be redirected automatically, otherwise please <a 
  href="doxygen/index.html">click here</a>.</p> 
</body>
```

You'll need to tweak the paths according to your set-up.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [this software](http://www.csparks.com/Relative/index.html) But I think I like Cheeseminer's solution better